# Excessive number casting & conversion?

Tags: c#, .net

I’m trying to improve my code’s "signal to noise ratio", hence would appreciate any tips on improving this, what appears to be smelly code. Perhaps there could also be potential performance improvements to be made here:

```
public class PricingInfoDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public decimal ListPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal Contribution
    {
        get
        {
            var contributionAmount = (1 + TaxRate) * (float)ListPrice * (ContributionPercentage / 100);
            return Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(Math.Min(ContributionMaximumAmount, contributionAmount), 2));
        }
        private set
        {
            // For NHibernate Map
        }
    }

    public float TaxRate { get; set; }

    public double ContributionMaximumAmount { get; set; }

    public float ContributionPercentage { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don’t have control over the types of properties, as the types of `ContributionMaximumAmount` & `ContributionPercentage` are enforced by the `ADO.NET` and the public `DataMember` is expected to be `Decimal`.

Comment: I'm not sure if `decimal` is actually going to help you when the source data is in `float`s and `double`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are ignoring the whole point of decimals. Which is to avoid rounding errors from floating point caclulations.

You must cast `TaxRate`, `ListPrice`, `ContributionPercentage`, etc. to `Decimal` and only then do your calculations using `Decimal` values. Casting at some point is unavoidable, if you have no control over signatures. You can, however, implement a wrapper, which would do the casting and expose `Decimal` properties. That will make your code more pretty.

Comment: thanks, up-voted for decimal suggestion, please see the revised code. Any more comments appreciated.

Comment: ah, changed my mind entirely in the end and created a `SetContribution` extension method for the `PricingInfoDto`. Now it (dto) looks nice & flat and I'm all **green**. Good time to break for lunch)

Comment: @Chuck, i think it is a bad idea. You should not move *core* logic to extension methods. Initialization should be done in constructor. Or inside of the getter, thats fine too. But surely not inside some extension method noone knows about.

Comment: that's the intention: dto is part of the API Contract and nobody needs to know what the internal workings out are. This is a service response data DTO and the extension method is internal to the contract namespace.

Comment: @Chuck, that is what `private` memebers are for. To hide the implemetation details. In my opinion "flat look" is not good enough reason to break the encapsulation (which you do by changing `private` to `internal`). It might not matter much in your case, but it is a bad practice nonetheless.

Comment: OK, you're right mate. I'm gonna refactor the query so that it selects the ContributionMaximumAmount and ContributionPercentage into some internal class and then work out the Contribution` amount and set it on the DTO in the query class. Cпасибо за помощь!